# c# long line of code formatting

Tags: c#, code-formatting

I wrote this line of code. It is unreadable. Is there clever way to break down it into multiple lines of code < 80 or 100 characters length?

`Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", testResults.Select(row => String.Join("|", row.Select(column => String.Format("{0,20}", column.ToString()))))));`

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you define clever?

Comment: one tip: column.ToString("...") should be used instead of the last String.Format.

Comment: I'd say it is not about formatting but nesting. Then, I would split this into multiple expressions, line after line,, with multiple temporary variables that store values used later.

Comment: @AntP thanks, I didn't know about this site

Comment: @TimBarrass let it be "readable" and "looks nice"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest separating *query* itself and its final *representation* (console output):

```
// Query: what to output
var testReport = testResults
  .Select(row => String.Join("|", row
     .Select(column => String.Format("{0,20}", column)))); // .ToString() is redundant

// Representation: how to output (print on the console in one go)
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, testReport));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the shortest way, if you don't want to split the assignment. But I would suggest to split it, so it's better to read.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",
                testResults.Select(
                    row => String.Join("|", row.Select(column => String.Format("{0,20}", column.ToString()))))));
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.. extract row.Select into a variable on the line above and use that. Also extract testResults.Select in the same way.

Comment: Why the downvotes?? This answer is almost exactly the same as the others, just no code.